# can't read selected value of dynamically created combobox

Tags: excel, vba

wasting way too much time on this...
I create a dynamic number of comboboxes like so:

```
Set MyComboBox = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", Name:="Combobox_" & x)

With MyComboBox
    .Left = 100
    .Top = 20 + x * 30
    .Height = 16
    .Width = 100

    'add a few fields 
    For Each col In fields
        myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines myForm.CodeModule.CountOfLines + 1, "Me.Combobox_" & x & ".AddItem (""" & CStr(col) & """)"
    Next
End With
```

which works fine. at the end I add an "OK" button that starts a function:

```
myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines myForm.CodeModule.CountOfLines + 1, "Private Sub cmd_1_Click()"
myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines myForm.CodeModule.CountOfLines + 1, "me.Hide"
myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines myForm.CodeModule.CountOfLines + 1, "Call BULK_DB_CHECK.Start_Check"
myForm.CodeModule.InsertLines myForm.CodeModule.CountOfLines + 1, "End Sub"
```

and here I fail:

```
Sub Start_Check()
UserForm2.Controls("Combobox_" & CStr(i)).ListIndex 'This is -1
UserForm2.Controls("Combobox_" & CStr(i)) 'This is ""
```

I simply want to read out the selected value of the Combobox, this is not in the userform code, but in a module. This worked with a list, but Fails with Combobox.... thanks for your help

Comment: That is only because of a lack of code... the Combobox is reachable, and I can print out the Name of the control element (which is of course Combobox_1, or Combobox_2....)

Comment: Could you post the complete code?

Comment: Why are you adding controls to the designer at run time rather than just adding them to the form on the fly?

Comment: @Rory because depending on the first Userform Input, there Need to be a different amount of control elements

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need to add them to the designer, rather than adding them directly to the form. It is very unusual to need to add controls to the designer.

Comment: @Rory can you point me somewhere where this is explained further? I couldn't get it to work otherwise

Comment: You use something like `userform2.controls.add` to add the controls. I'm afraid your question is far too vague for me to be more specific than that.

Comment: I just tested here with some bogus code and textboxes instead of comboboxes and it worked for me. Please post the complete code.

I THINK your `Sub Start_Check()` may need to change to something like `Sub Start_Check(f as userform)` and then you replace `Userform2` with `f`, but I still need more code to understand what actually works and what not.

Answer (score 0):

On the part you mention it fails, you are never defining the value of `i`. So it is trying to find "Combobox_"(because `i` is empty). If I am not mistaken, it starts at least with 1.

I am also not sure if there is a difference for VBA between `Combobox` and `ComboBox`, but I would use `ComboBox`

Comment: see comment under question

Comment: Also - Combobox_i is the name I give to the element. ComboBox is the name of the type of control element. stupid, i know

Comment: The capitalization part I am actually not sure if it would make any difference, since I am not used to create them dynamically. I just mentioned in case it made any difference :)